# How do I extract only numbers(no duplicates) from a text file and find the sum?

Tags: regex, string, perl, sum

For example I have a sentence like:

"There are 99 cars in over 99 countries, 50 of which are defective."

I need to find out how to get 99 + 50, so basically all the numbers without duplicates in a string and add them together.

I am aware that I should use a regular expression to extract the numbers from the string and then split them and place a "+" sign in front of them, but everything I've tried keeps giving me the wrong numbers to work with.

Comment: `my @nums = $sentence =~ /\d+/g;`

Comment: @mpapec You need to use a hash to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 5):

For integers:

```
use List::Util 'sum';
use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';

my $total = sum( uniq( $sentence =~ /\d+/g ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sum` from List::Util to sum the numbers. Use a hash to get a list of unique numbers.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use List::Util qw{ sum };

my $string = 'There are 99 cars in over 99 countries, 50 of which are defective.';
my %nums;
undef $nums{$1} while $string =~ /([0-9]+)/g;
print sum(keys %nums), "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Using more OO approach, but basically wrapped `List::Util` and `List::MoreUtils` by [`perl5i`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perl5i)

```
use perl5i::2;
# strict and warnings enabled by default

my $sum = [ $sentence =~ /\d+/g ]->uniq->sum;
```

Comment: Thanks for the amusing 5i version.  Haven't seen this in action much, but it's fun.  +1